# how to evaluate Regular expression for max 15 digits excluding 4 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have tried the following regular expression for my validation but it is resulting in false and im not able to get the solution. I want it to validate for Max 15 digits excluding 4 decimal places. Can anybody guide me through this?

```
    var patt = new RegExp("[-+]?\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?$");
    var res = patt.test(txtFxRateAgainstUSD.value);
    if (!res)
    {
        errMsg = errMsg + "Enter Rate in valid format: (Max 15 digits excluding 4 decimal places).\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: Double escape it: `new RegExp("^[-+]?\\d{1,15}(\\.\\d{1,4})?$");` or use regex literal `/^[-+]?\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?$/`

Comment: Could you clarify *I want it to validate for Max 15 digits excluding 4 decimal places* requirement? Any sample inputs? You also need the start of string anchor `^` at the start, BTW. And surely use a regex literal notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the digit character `d` and dot character `.` with double slash.So that your string literal can express it as data before transforming it into a regular expression.

Code:

```
var regPattern = new RegExp("^[-+]?\\d{1,15}(\\.\\d{1,4})?$");

if(!regPattern.test(txtFxRateAgainstUSD.value)) 
{
    errMsg = errMsg + "Enter Rate in valid format: (Max 15 digits excluding 4 decimal places).\r\n";
}
```

Comment: There is no use in a RegExp constructor notation if the pattern is static. Use the regex literal notation. Also, it is not a good idea to take someone else's comment and use it in your answer. Even if you tested it. Can you at least explain why it should work?

Comment: Thanks @Lokesh_Ram